# Keras softmax probabilities

Tags: keras, softmax

I'm trying to get softmax probabilities from a net whose last layer is a softmax layer and when I use model.predict() I get classes instead probabilities. Could anyone tell how to get probabilities.

```
 model = Sequential() 
 model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3,input_shape=(32, 32, 3))) 
 model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2))) 
 model.add(Dropout(0.5))
 model.add(Activation('relu'))
 model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
 model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2))) 
 model.add(Dropout(0.5))
 model.add(Activation('relu'))
 model.add(Flatten())      
 model.add(Dense(128))
 model.add(Activation('relu')) 
 model.add(Dense(43)) 
 model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Comment: Please provide more information, if the network has a softmax output, then model.predict will return those probabilities. If you are not seeing probabilities then there is something wrong in the code.

Comment: What do you understand by "classes" and "probabilities"? Softmax will always return the "chance" of all classes, summing 1.

Comment: show your model-building code please

Comment: my net is:.My net is: 
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3,input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(43))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

Comment: When I use model.predict(pics_data[0:6], batch_size=32, verbose=1) I get zeros and a one instead of probabilities (I think is directly the class predicted)

Comment: I just copy the model into the main question for clarity

Answer (score 1):

Your model's outputs will be values between 0 and 1.
Your model should give a vector of size 43 and the sum of all outputs will add to one.

Depending on your training, these "probabilities" will often be almost one for the selected class if similar to the training examples, showing that the model was well trained.